# Hive nested get_json_object works fine in select query but returns null in create table as select query - weird behavior

Tags: sql, hive

I have a hive table which has 3 columns, such that combining 1 of them is a string, second is a string-ified json array and third is a string-ified json object. I want to retrieve a field from the string-ified json object, whose relevant key can be obtained by combining 1st column with 1st element in the string-fied json array in second array.

```
get_json_object(
get_json_object(
column3,concat(
"$.",column1,"__",
get_json_object(
column2,"$[0]"
))),
"$.fieldofinterest") 
as field_of_interest
```

I wrote the above construct, to retrieve the field of interest.

When this is written as part of a `select...from` statement, I get the correct output in `field_of_interest` column.

When it is written as part of a `create table t1 as select...from` statement, the table gets created where `field_of_interest` is `NULL` for all rows.

There is no failure in the `create...select` statement. All other columns get populated fine. I am using `get_json_object` in other columns, they are not nested. They populate fine. Only this column doesn't.

What could be causing this? How can I begin to debug this? Had no luck with other stack-overflow answers.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. It was because of version gap between where I was testing my query and where I was eventually running it.

I was testing it on hiveserver2. It ran on a spark 2.2 backend, where `get_json_object` is able to parse json arrays. On the server, where I was running it, hive 0.13 version was running which doesn't parse JSON arrays. I wrapped the array in an object and it worked like a charm.

```
get_json_object(
 get_json_object(
  column3, 
   concat(
    "$.",
    column1,
    "__",
    get_json_object(
     concat('{"x":',column2,'}'),
     "$.x[0]"
    )
   )
  ),
 "$.fieldofinterest"
) as field_of_interest
```